# Jquery Slide bar Gallary

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, gallery

I want a gallery slide bar like http://www.greggs.co.uk/
is there any jquery tools for doing this?
thanks

Comment: Thanks for all answers.
I'll make that and publish it.as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like the **simplyScroll** plugin...

http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/